# launch a SQL query from the js file

Tags: javascript, smartclient

in my JS file I need to do a search on the DB (select * from table where condition) and store the result in an array(multidimensional)
do you have an idea how to do it ?
thank you in advance

Comment: check this link--http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13899650/is-it-possible-to-retrieve-data-from-sql-server-using-jquery

Comment: Write SQL in a Javascript is bad idea. You should use Ajax to send data to server. Then server file will execute the appropriate SQL. Then Server file will response your output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the best solution is to use the dataSource files using the `<customSQL>` tag , here is an example:

```
  <operationBindings>
      <operationBinding operationType="fetch">
         <customSQL>
         SELECT  Name, Adress, Phone, Age                       
        FROM tableName
            where Age >20

           </customSQL>
     </operationBinding>
  </operationBindings>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't write any code in your `JavaScript` related to `Database`.

**In `Smart GWT` always access database using [DataSource](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/data/DataSource.html)**

**You can use [GWT JSNI](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html) to call Java method from JavaScript and vice-verse.**

Find a sample code on [Calling GWT Java function from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16080099/calling-gwt-java-function-from-javascript)

Comment: I never suggest you to use it but still you can look at [Is it possible to retrieve data from SQL Server using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13899650/is-it-possible-to-retrieve-data-from-sql-server-using-jquery?lq=1)